# How to import an application service into a library

Tags: angular6

I have enter the code on these file.

```
src/assets/icons/svg/noun/a.sv
src/assets/icons/svg/svgs.ts
```

In app directory I have the following service that attempts to access `svgs.ts`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { svgs } from '../assets/icons/svg/svgs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

  constructor() {  }

  get svgs(){
    return svgs
  }
}
```

In a forms library with an `autocomponent.ts`, I attempt to import the `app.service` with the following import:

```
import { AppService } from '../../../../../../src/app/app-service.service'
```

My attempt to build the forms  but the library always came out the errors:

```
'zimmer/src/app/app.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'Z:\workspace\zimm\projects\forms\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

Can I create a service in the application and use it in a projects library? If can how can I do it?

Thanks.